# scrapy - how to get text from 'div'

Tags: html, text, scrapy, web-crawler

I just started to get to know scrapy. Now I am trying to crawl by following tutorials. But I have difficulty to crawl text from div.

This is items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Fied
class DmozItem(Item):
    name = Field()
    title = Field()
    pass
```

This is dmoz_spider.py

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item

from dmoz.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["roxie.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.roxie.com/events/details.cfm?eventID=4921702B-9E3D-8678-50D614177545A594"]

    def parse(self, response):
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            sites = hxs.select('//div[@id="eventdescription"]')
            items = []
            for site in sites:
                    item = DmozItem()
                    item['name'] = hxs.select("text()").extract()
                    items.append(item)
            return items
```

And now I am trying to crawl from top folder by commanding this:

```
scrapy crawl dmoz -o scraped_data.json -t json
```

But the file was created with only '['.

It perfectly works in the console(by commanding each select), but somehow it doesn't work as a script. I am really a starter of scrapy. Could you guys let me know how can I get the data in 'div'? Thanks in advance.

*** In addition, this is what I get.

```
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: dmoz)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/twisted/web/microdom.py:181: SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?
assert (oldChild.parentNode is self,
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [dmoz] INFO: Spider opened
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [dmoz] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [dmoz] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.roxie.com/events/details.cfm?eventID=4921702B-9E3D-8678-50D614177545A594> (referer: None)
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [dmoz] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [dmoz] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 281,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 27451,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 19, 15, 43, 56, 569164),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 4,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 19, 15, 43, 56, 417661)}
2013-06-19 08:43:56-0700 [dmoz] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Just to check, what exactly do you want the name field to be populated by? "DOC FEST: MY WAY TO OLYMPIA" or something else?

Comment: Yes, also I want to get the description of movie and img file. Could you let me know what I missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can get you the title of the film, but I'm somewhat crappy with XPath so the description XPath will get you *everything* within the `<div class="tabbertab" title="Synopsis">` element. It's not ideal, but it's a starting point. Getting the image URL is left as an exercise for the OP. :)

```
from scrapy.item import Field, Item


class DmozItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    description = Field()


class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["roxie.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.roxie.com/events/details.cfm?eventID=4921702B-9E3D-8678-50D614177545A594"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = DmozItem()
        item["title"] = hxs.select('//div[@style="width: 100%;"]/text()').extract()
        item["description"] = hxs.select('//div[@class="tabbertab"]').extract()
        return item
```

Comment: It definitely works! Thanks Talvalin. Due to your help, I can crawl all the other information I want!

Comment: Good to hear. Well, if both answers were useful, then pick the most useful as the accepted answer and upvote both please. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just replace

```
item['name'] = hxs.select("text()").extract()
```

with

```
item['name'] = site.select("text()").extract()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, I tried it, but it doesn't work. Still it makes the JSON file that contains only '['.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer (removed [0]) - so that there will be the list in the output json name value.

Comment: Yei! It was path problem. Thanks alecxe! Because of your comment that it works for me, I started all the works at different path, and it works.